# Using x-www-form-urlencoded data on JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, postman

I am using postman to hit programmr.com api and the snapshot sucessfully looks like this:

[image]

Curl version:  pastebin.com/GQDZJALj

And then I'm trying to hit the API using JQUERY using following code:

```
var data = "InputJSON:" +  JSON.stringify({  "mode": "java_example",  "apiKey": "bb6b589027a097b38e8cc47cffb8e70a",  "files": [    {      "name": "Test.java",      "content": "class Test{\n    \n public static void main(String[] arg){\n     \n     System.out.println(\"wwwwwww!!\");     \n  }\n\n}\n\n"    }  ], "eval code": ""});

          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "http://console.programmr.com/api/eval",
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:  data,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                return response;
            }
```

Raw string data:

```
InputJSON:{"mode":"java_example","apiKey":"bb6b589027a097b38e8cc47cffb8e70a","files":[{"name":"Test.java","content":"class Test{\n    \n public static void main(String[] arg){\n     \n     System.out.println(\"wwwwwww!!\");     \n  }\n\n}\n\n"}],"eval code":""}
```

The APIs response keep saying that my JSon is Invalid

```
{error: "Invalid JSON"}
```

My question is how to request to the API using the Javascript/JQuery just like postman done?

Any help will be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks in advance

updated:

it should be:

```
 var data = "InputJSON=" +  JSON.stringify({  "mode": "java_example",  "apiKey": "bb6b589027a097b38e8cc47cffb8e70a",  "files": [    {      "name": "Test.java",      "content": "class Test{\n    \n public static void main(String[] arg){\n     \n     System.out.println(\"wwwwwww!!\");     \n  }\n\n}\n\n"    }  ], "eval code": ""});
```

Comment: Is `InputJSON` supposed to be the POST parameter name here? In that case you should not do string concatenation with `:` in between, but pass this as a proper object with that key, and your data. You should not even need to specify contentType and the additional header then, because those are default.

Comment: please check my postman snaphot, yes, it's should be there

Comment: Then try adding `processData: false`, so that jQuery leaves your data as-is, and doesn’t try any additional manipulation/transformation of it.

Comment: oh okay I will try, I will let you know about the result, btw this is the curl version https://pastebin.com/GQDZJALj

Comment: And why is that cURL version using `InputJSON={ "mode": `?

Comment: ah, still unlucky just added  processData: false, to the AJAX code and it still as it

Comment: @CBroe I am just following this doc http://console.programmr.com/

Comment: And where in there did you find `InputJSON:`? Every single example I see on that page uses `InputJSON=`

Comment: hi thanks you, I made a typo here, you just helped me from wasting more time, how about put your comment to the answer then I can mark it as an Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InputJSON` is supposed to be the POST parameter name here, so it should not be concatenated with the data with `:` in between.

It should follow the normal `name=value` format.